# Unable to add ListRow to ListObject with worksheet protected using UserInterfaceOnly:=true

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add a new row to a table using the ListRows.Add method. The table is on an excel worksheet protected using:

```
ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

I thought this would allow me to add the ListRow without having to unprotect and then re-protect the worksheet, but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: I've posted a solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832694/8488913](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832694/8488913)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this *undocumentd feature* and, unfortunatetely, the only wokaround I've found is to unprotect the sheet before any table methods are applied and then reprotect after.

Comment: Seems strange that it won't work. I guess I'll have to stick with protecting and unprotecting. Cheers Mark

Comment: same here (Excel 2010) - maybe you can work around with `.Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown` which works on my end

Comment: @snibbo I've posted a solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832694/8488913](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832694/8488913)